# Lower bound for Merge Sort running time

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

I'm trying to prove that the recurrence $T(n)=2T(\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor) + n$ is in $\Omega(n \log_2 n)$.

Here's my attempt: Suppose there is some $c>0$ and a positive integer $n_0$ such that $n_0 \le k < n \implies T(k) \ge ck \log_2 k$.

Then

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
T(n) &=& 2T(\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor) + n \\
&\ge& 2c \left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor \log_2 \left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor + n \\
&\ge& 2c \left ( \frac{n - 1}{2} \right ) \log_2 \left ( \frac{n - 1}{2} \right ) + n \\
&=& c(n - 1) \log_2(n - 1) - c(n - 1) + n \\
&=& cn \log_2(n-1) - c \log_2(n-1) - c(n - 1) + n \\
&=& cn \log_2 \left [ n \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right ) \right ] - c \log_2(n-1) - c(n - 1) + n \\
&=& cn \log_2 n + cn \log_2 \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right ) - c \log_2(n-1) - c(n - 1) + n.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

I can't determine if there is a $c > 0$ such that $cn \log_2 \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right ) - c \log_2(n-1) - c(n - 1) + n$ is non-negative for $n$ large enough.

Also, I think this approach is too complicated given how easy it is to prove $T(n)=O(n \log_2 n)$. Am I missing some obvious estimate here?

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: "Suppose there is some $c>0$ and a positive integer $n_0$ such that $n_0 \le k < n \implies T(k) \ge ck \log_2 k$." What is $n$ here?

Comment: It's a positive integer for which I want to prove(by induction) the bound $T(n) \ge cn \log_2 n$.

Answer (score 1):

$c=\frac{1}{2}$ is enough for large enough $n$.

Indeed, there are positive integers $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
n &\ge& n_1 \implies -\frac{1}{2} < \log_2 \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right ) \\
n &\ge& n_2 \implies -\frac{1}{2} < -\frac{1}{n} \log_2 (n - 1).
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Rewriting $$cn \log_2 \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right ) - c \log_2(n-1) - c(n - 1) + n$$

as

$$
cn \left [ \log_2 \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right ) - \frac{1}{n} \log_2(n-1) + \frac{1}{n} - 1 + \frac{1}{c} \right ],
$$

we have

$$n \ge \max(n_1, n_2) \implies -2 + \frac{1}{c} < \log_2 \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right ) - \frac{1}{n} \log_2(n-1) + \frac{1}{n} - 1 + \frac{1}{c}.$$

But $-2 + \frac{1}{c} \ge 0 \iff c \le \frac{1}{2}$.